# New Instances using Reflexion into Dictionary (c#)

Tags: c#, dictionary, types, reflection

I use Reflection to load some especific classes and create new instances of  each found class. Here code

class Program {

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
 
 Container typeContainer = new Container(); // Where i want set the instances

 GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                 .Where(type => type.IsClass) //Filter by class
                 .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Model")) // Another Filter by class name 
                 .ToList() // Set found Types in to a List
                 .ForEach(modelType => {
                     // for each Type then create a new instance using the fullname                
                     object component = viewModelType.Assembly.CreateInstance(modelType.FullName);
                     // Then add the instance into the typeContainer
                     typeContainer.AddComponent(component);
                 });  
}


public class Container {

        private Dictionary<Type, object> Component { get; } = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

        public void AddComponent<T>(T componentName)
        {
            Component[typeof(T)] = componentName;
        }

}    

}
```

So the Reflexion logic works well the classes that i ned will be found.

problem it's that wen i want to add the instances using "AddComponent" will be just add one of then.

The Questions are:

1. For example when using reflexion i found some elements, why will be just add one of then into typeContainer ?
2. Why typeContainer.AddComponent(component) doenst Work like typeContainer.AddComponent(new AnotheClassName()), what it is die diferent?
3. its posible to have the same results than typeContainer.AddComponent(new AnotheClassName()) using reflexion?

I put some debug Screenshoots to give more information about the debug resulst,it is no 100 Identical that the code postet but it just to see that the List using reflection has for example 3 elements but the element typeContainer has added just on of then , after the loop.

[image]

Thanks for advance

(Project use .net Framework 4.5)

Best Regards Javanto

Comment: What is "Reflexion?"  Is that a new library?

Comment: Nothing there seems to look like its not part of the standard framework. I assume its a a misspelling of reflection. i.e `System.Reflection`

Comment: It looks like this code should work - are you sure that this isn't working? The `.ForEach` method should ensure that `CreateInstance` is called as many times as there are types discovered - what issues are you seeing?

Comment: Trying to put all code in a single line or chain of calls is a bad idea as you found out, because neither you nor others have any idea what's going on. Same goes for sentences. The question is *very* hard to read and it's unclear what the problem is. Or even if there *is* a question

Comment: Split the code into separate lines and check what the actual results are at each point. There may be just a single object matching your criteria. Or, all objects have the same type, so obviously, `AddComponent` keep replacing the same entry

Comment: You can use `GetType()` to get an object's type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll work if you change AddComponent to:

```
        public void AddComponent(object instance)
        {
            Component[instance.GetType()] = instance;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks i have second Method create with this logic and it work like i want , just  need to see how i can use one mthod for everything that comes!